# Emacs shortcuts specific for a file type

Tags: emacs

is there a way to get different shortcut for different file types?
Tipically I use <kbd>F12</kbd> to compile. It runs `make -f`. I'd like to have <kbd>F12</kbd> running

> M-x org-export-as-html

when I'm on Org-mode.
How should I edit my .emacs file? Currently it's just:

> (global-set-key [f12] 'compile)

Thanks,
hamen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a mode hook for org-mode that does a `local-set-key` instead of a `global-set-key`

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key [f12] 'org-export-as-html)))
```

Comment: Should (lambda ... be '(lambda ... ?

Comment: I believe lambda is self-quoting, so, no.

Answer (score 4):

The clean way to add bindings on a file type basis is to the bindings to the modes themselves:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f12>") 'org-export-as-html)
```

See [Changing Key Bindings](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html), [Keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps.html#Keymaps), and [Major Mode Conventions](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Mode-Conventions.html#Major-Mode-Conventions)