# How to override/change mode key bindings in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In particular, when I load dired-x, it sets M-o to toggle the omit minor mode. I use M-o for other-window, so I would like to change the key that dired-x binds to something else. I've attempted setting the key after the mode loads like this:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (dired-omit-mode 1)
    (global-set-key (kbd "M-o") 'other-window)
    ))
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Tried looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773820/emacs-shortcuts-specific-for-a-file-type/3773856#3773856 ?

Comment: Didn't find that one, thanks. It's the same answer as the accepted one below.

Comment: I love stack overflow: not only is this exactly what I wanted, it's also exactly the keybinding I wanted...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slightly better than adding another copy of your custom global binding to the local mode map, would be removing the local binding so that it no longer shadows the global binding. You might also give that function a new key before you do this.

```
(eval-after-load "dired-x"
  '(progn
     ;; Add an alternative local binding for the command
     ;; bound to M-o
     (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-c o")
       (lookup-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-o")))
     ;; Unbind M-o from the local keymap
     (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-o") nil)))
```

Answer (score 5):

The dired-mode bindings "shadow" the global ones so your "global-set-key" isn't helping. What you want to do is override the dired-mode binding:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (dired-omit-mode 1)
    (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-o") 'other-window)
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else with this question, it's not necessary to put the define-key inside the hook.

Comment: But it is necessary that `dired-mode-map` exists when you use it.